# unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'DatetimeArray' and 'DatetimeArray'

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime, python-datetime

**Sanctioned Date:- DateTime column**

```
a = df[df['Sanctioned Date'] >= '2022-01-01']
```

```
b = df[df['Sanctioned Date'] <= '2022-06-16']
```

want :-  `a & b`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Output of `a, b` is filtered DataFrame, so cannot chain by `&`.

You can chain masks with `()`:

```
out = df[(df['Sanctioned Date'] >= '2022-01-01') & (df['Sanctioned Date'] <= '2022-06-16')]
```

Or use [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
out = df[df['Sanctioned Date'].between('2022-01-01', '2022-06-16')]
```

Your solution has to be changed with remove `df[]` first for possible chain masks:

```
a = df['Sanctioned Date'] >= '2022-01-01'
b = df['Sanctioned Date'] <= '2022-06-16'
out = df[a & b]
```